# How to get into the split screen mode in Maxthon?

Tags: macos, web-browser

How to get into the split screen mode in Maxthon?

I have tried pressing F10. Also I google it but can't find another way to split it?

Maxthon's version 4.1.3.5000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're all already gone..
go back to Maxthon version 4.4.8.1000
you'll get it all.. back :D